# Not able to `focus` editable `div` element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I would like to set the focus to one of my `contentEditable` div element. but not working.

here is my code:

```js
$(document).click(function () {
    $('div').focus();
});
```

```css
div{
    border:1px solid red;   
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable >&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working snippet without using jQuery (which you do not load in your snippet). I also added an ID to get the correct `div`.

```js
document.getElementById('edit-me').focus();
```

```css
div { border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<div id="edit-me" contentEditable>&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wait until the entire document is loaded before executing jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').click(function () {
        $('div').focus();
    })
});
```

```css
div{
    border:1px solid red;   
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable >&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Import jquery! Yay!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //I replaced "click" with "ready" because think that you want to focus once loaded, not once you click somewhere in the document.
    //"click" can still be used if you want to focus once you clicked somewhere in your window
    $('div').focus();
});
```

```css
div{
    border:1px solid red;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contentEditable >&nbsp;</div>
```